# How to specify -W4 (Visual Studio) in a Qt project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qmake

My environment:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
- Qt 5.6.2
- Qt Creator 4.8.1

I want to compile my C++ project with `-W4` instead of the default `-W3`, so I added this line to my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -W4
```

But then, I get many of these warnings (one for each compilation unit, I suppose):

```
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W4' with '/W3'
```

From the command line, I can see that the command line does include both `-W3` and `-W4` (in this order).

So, my question: **How can I swap the order of `-W3` and `-W4` (so `-W4` would take precedence over `-W3`)?**

Note that **this did not work**: I tried to modify Qt's configuration file `C:\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf`, by changing the value of variable `QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON` from `-W3` to `-W4`, and not adding `-W4` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` in my `.pro` file, but that caused many (thousands) of warnings being generated by libraries. I also tried to append `-W4` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` (instead of `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`) in my `.pro` file, with the same result (thousands of warnings from libraries).

Also note that if I add `-Wall` (instead of `-W4`) to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, then:

- I do not get similar command line warnings (although `-Wall` is
  followed by `-W3` on the command line)
- I still get many warnings from libraries, but considerably less than
  with `-W3` changed to `-W4` in `msvc-desktop.conf` (or with `-W4` appended to
  `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` in my `.pro` file).

I use qmake (through Qt Creator), so any solutions that would require editing the generated Visual Studio project files would be unacceptable.

Comment: I don't have access to visual studio  right now, so this might not be exactly correct, but you can edit the warning level by rightclicking to your project -> properties->c/c++->change warning level

Comment: but that caused many (thousands) of warnings being generated by libraries - seems like an expected result to me

Comment: @Lorand My post now explains why this is not acceptable.

Comment: @VTT See the mention of `-Wall` in the updated version of my post.

Comment: `How can I swap the order of -W3 and -W4 (so -W4 would take precedence over -W3)?` `QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON = -W4 $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON`

Comment: @Matt Your suggestion does not work, for three reasons. 1) Your suggestion results in `-W4` being placed before `-W3`, which is the opposite of the desired result. 2) Manipulating `QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON` in the `.pro` file has no impact on my project, which is C++ only. 3) As I told in my post, appending `-W4` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` (not to `QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON`) in my `.pro` file results in tons of warnings from libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change to your project file *appends* the warning setting to the existing variable, which is predefined:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -W4
```

You could either prepend the variable, or actually [replace the existing warning variable setting](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#replacing-values) with your own:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS ~= s/-W3/-W4
```

Comment: As I wrote in my post, `-W4` (which I appended to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`) is overridden on the command line by `-W3` (which apparently comes from `QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON`, which is set in `msvc-desktop.conf`). And replacing `-W3` by `-W4` has no effect (`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is probably empty initially).

Comment: Replacing `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` by `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` in your second suggestion, like this: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON ~= s/-W3/-W4`, seems to solve all my problems. Thanks!

Comment: @user1387866 Great to hear!